# Arranging multiple plots in a grid inside a figure/subfloat

Tags: subfloats, grids

I have a grid of pie charts which go into `subfloat`s. The number is odd, and I would like to have them on a 3x2 grid, where the cell in the bottom left is empty. I have simulated this by putting an empty subfloat in the following example, but obviously that's not good, as I get a sub-caption labelled "(e)" and the caption count is increased:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[first]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\subfloat[second]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\hspace{0mm}
\subfloat[third]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\subfloat[forth]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\hspace{0mm}
\subfloat[]{   % ???
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{empty.pdf}
}
\subfloat[fifth]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If a naive solution is also OK:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{it} &   \includegraphics[width=65mm]{it} \\
(a) first & (b) second \\[6pt]
 \includegraphics[width=65mm]{it} &   \includegraphics[width=65mm]{it} \\
(c) third & (d) fourth \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=65mm]{it} }\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(e) fifth}
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is another picture, of course.

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot, the fifth sub-figure is centered. I would like to have it aligned with the right column of the grid, i.e. directly under the fourth sub-figure.

Comment: @EmitTaste Oh,I see. Non-centered version is easier, of course. One should only omit `\multicolumn` etc.

Comment: you hard coded the `(a)`, `(b)`, ....!

Comment: Really great answer, helped me a ton.

Comment: Question, I was trying to use this simple solution, but the captions I am using are too long and the environment isn't wrapping the lines.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution would be to use subfigures. You can get an empty left-bottom cell by increasing the width of the bottom figure (whilst keeping the image width the same) and using `\raggedleft`.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMAGE NAME}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMAGE NAME}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMAGE NAME}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMAGE NAME}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{IMAGE NAME}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[short]{A beautiful, well written caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You then get something like this: (I used some graphs I was working with as a place holder):

[image]

(You can still add subcaptions etc using the `subfigure` package). Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: What about the caption of the last figure? With your solution, it will get centered in the middle of the page, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I figured, a simple solution it prepend a `\hbox to 67.5mm{}` at the right spot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[first]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\subfloat[second]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\newline
\subfloat[third]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\subfloat[forth]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\newline
\hbox to 67.5mm{}% !!
\subfloat[fifth]{
  \includegraphics[width=65mm]{test.pdf}
}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```