# How to create a 2 by 3 grid of figures?

Tags: floats

I have six figures. I want to create a single figure with 6 subfigures each with its own caption and, if possible, a global caption.

I have tried and subflots, subfigure, tables and none of that worked.

With subfigure I can't figure out how to tell it to create three rows of figures instead of the compiler resolving it to a six figures in one column. If I add two figures I get them side by side. I add a third and/or a fourth I get one column.

With tables, I can do what I want however I can't figure out how to add the caption to each subfigure.

With subfloat I get this error: 
! Undefined control sequence.
 \sf@counterlist

When using it like in this question: [Arranging multiple plots in a grid inside a figure/subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140833/arranging-multiple-plots-in-a-grid-inside-a-figure-subfloat)

I know I should be copying code but it is way too large since all pictures are tickzpictures. I was wondering if anywone could provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Have you tried changing the separation between the subfigures? I.e. having for example `\begin{subfigure} ... \end{subfigure}~\begin{subfigure} ... \end{subfigure}`
~ puts the figures on the same row, a blank line puts the next figure on the next row. See the subfigure section [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)

Comment: I had a blank line between each subfigure. I replaced all of these blank lines with \hfill and now it is working. Thank you!